# How do I change the value of a button only when all required fields are filled in?

Tags: jquery

How can I change the value of a button only when all required fields are filled in the form?

**THE SCRIPT**

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $(this).val('We are logging you in...');
});
```

**THE FORM**

```
<form method='post' action="dashboard.php" id="login">
    <input id="username" type="email" name="userName" placeholder="Email address">            
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</form>

<input type="submit" id="myButton" name='logIn' class="button" value="Login">
```

Here's the fiddle that I can work up to: http://jsfiddle.net/stan255/a5k25/

How can I accomplish this goal with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#myButton').click(function(){
var allValidated = true;
$('#login input').each(function(){
if($(this).val()=="")
      allValidated = false;
})
if(allValidated)
  $(this).val('We are logging you in...');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5k25/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var cache = $('input:not([type="submit"])');
    var condition = cache.filter(function(){ return $(this).val() !== ""; }).length === cache.length;
    if(condition){ $(this).val('We are logging you in...'); }
    else { $(this).val('We are not gonna log you in...'); }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5k25/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Used your Fiddle code :
 Assuming you are using email as your first input.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var email = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if(validateEmail(email) && password!= ''){
     $(this).val('We are logging you in...');
    } else {
      //Your error msg here
      return false;
    }

});

function validateEmail(email){
    var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    var valid = emailReg.test(email);

    if(!valid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using **`blur`** event handler,

1) Collect all the textbox fields excluding the sumit button.

```
var allInps = $('input').not('input[type="submit"]');
```

2) Now attach the **`blur`** event handler to perform the below actions

3) create a `boolean` variable(`ch`), to check whether all mandatory fields are filled, then *iterate* each `textbox` elements and check its *value's length* and change the value of `boolean` variable(`ch`) based on it.

```
allInps.on('blur', function () {
    var ch = false;
    $.each(allInps, function (i, v) {
        if ($(v).val().length !== 0) 
            ch = true;
        else 
            ch = false;
    });
    if (ch)  
       $('#myButton').val('NOW U CAN LOGIN');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/a5k25/6/)